# How to add multiple slider support to a simple jquery slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple slider with jquery; it supports only one slider, and I want to make it support multiple sliders on the same page.

Example: Slider 1, Slider 2, Slider 3 etc. on the same page.

A working snippet is here [working example](https://codepen.io/dlkkn/pen/KKvdePb).

I know I have to use each function—and I did—but it stopped working. I don't know where I am going wrong. This is what I tried; the code was too long, so I shortened it:

```
$('#slider').each(function() {
  var current_slider = $(this);
  //slider codes in here 
});
```

Here is my complete code:

```
$(function(){    
var Slider = 0;
$.Slider = function(total){
   $("#indicator li").removeClass("active");
   $("#image li").hide();
   if (Slider < total -1){
       Slider++;
         $("#indicator li:eq("+Slider+")").addClass("active");
         $("#image li:eq("+Slider+")").fadeIn("slow");                                    
       }else {
         $("#indicator li:first").addClass("active");
         $("#image li:first").fadeIn("slow");    
         Slider = 0;    
       }
   }

   var totalLi = $("#indicator li").length;
   var interval = setInterval('$.Slider('+totalLi+')',5000);
   $("#slider").hover(function(){
      clearInterval(interval);
   },function(){
      interval = setInterval('$.Slider('+totalLi+')',5000);    
   });

   $("#indicator li:first").addClass("active");
   $("#image li").hide();
   $("#image li:first").show();
   $("#indicator li").hover(function(){
      var indicators = $(this).index();
      $("#indicator li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $("#image li").hide();
      $("#image li:eq("+indicators+")").fadeIn("slow");                                   
      Slider = indicators;
      return true;   
   });  
});
```

I don't want to repeat the same code for each slider.
I want it to support multiple sliders like this [example](https://codepen.io/jakecigar/pen/ERrwqg); that example uses each function to get all the sliders, but it doesn't have `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and indicators in it.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to turn it to support multiple sliders" ? It would be useful if you could do a snippet to showcase what its not working and clarify what you want to accomplish that que current code isn't.

Comment: @Gass added more info and demo link in question

Comment: id attribute must be unique within a HTML document. Currently, you have two slider with same id. Once you have two separate slider with different id, you should be able to make it work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use `.closest()` and `.find()` method to traverse through the current element which is hover . Then , you can use `each` loop to iterate through slider and get the index of current active li and depending on the position make next li active .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $.Slider = function(total) {
  //loop through all slider
    $(".slider-holder").each(function() {
      var index = $(this).find(".carousel-indicators .active").index() + 1; //get index of active ..class + 1 
      $(this).find(".carousel-indicators li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).find(".image-slide li").hide();
      if (index < total) {
        $(this).find(".carousel-indicators li:eq(" + index + ") ").addClass("active");
        $(this).find(".image-slide li:eq(" + index + ")").fadeIn("slow");
      } else {
        $(this).find(".carousel-indicators  li:eq(0)").addClass("active");
        $(this).find(".image-slide li:eq(0)").fadeIn("slow");
      }
    })
  }

  var totalLi = $(".slider-holder:eq(0) .carousel-indicators li").length;
  var interval = setInterval('$.Slider(' + totalLi + ')', 5000);
  $(".slider-holder").hover(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }, function() {
    interval = setInterval('$.Slider(' + totalLi + ')', 5000);
  });

  $(".carousel-indicators li").hover(function() {
    var indicators = $(this).index();
    var selector = $(this); //current li hover...
    selector.closest(".carousel-indicators").find("li").removeClass("active"); // to add clas..
    selector.addClass("active");
    selector.closest(".slider-holder").find(" .image-slide > li").hide();
    selector.closest(".slider-holder").find(".image-slide > li:eq(" + indicators + ")").fadeIn("slow");
    return true;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-holder {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.slider-holder ul,
li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.slider-holder .content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.carousel-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  list-style: none;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-indent: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(15, 15, 20, 0.7);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
}

.carousel-indicators li:hover,
.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider-holder" id="slider">
  <ul class="image-slide" id="image">
    <li>
      <div class="img-fluid" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/13/22/53/puzzle-3223941__480.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/07/13/57/puzzle-1721619__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/07/14/13/puzzle-1721635__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/18/20/01/frankfurt-4945405__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/05/11/19/internet-315132__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="carousel-indicators" id="buton">
    <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
    <li><span>2</span></li>
    <li><span>3</span></li>
    <li><span>4</span></li>
    <li><span>5</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>



<h1> Second slider </h1>
<div class="slider-holder" style="width: 40%;float:right;">
  <ul class="image-slide">
    <li>
      <div class="img-fluid" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/13/22/53/puzzle-3223941__480.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/07/13/57/puzzle-1721619__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/07/14/13/puzzle-1721635__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/18/20/01/frankfurt-4945405__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/05/11/19/internet-315132__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Heading</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li class="active"><span>1</span></li>
    <li><span>2</span></li>
    <li><span>3</span></li>
    <li><span>4</span></li>
    <li><span>5</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved me, I tried each and find function to do that but didnt have enough knowledge to complete it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Your slider in a simple web page</title>

   <style>
   body { background-color: #fff; color: #000; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
   .container { width: 900px; margin: auto; padding-top: 1em; }
   .container .ism-slider { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
   </style>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="ism/css/my-slider.css"/>
   <script src="ism/js/ism-2.2.min.js"></script>

   </head>
   <body>
   <div class='container'>

   <div class="ism-slider" id="my-slider">
   <ol>
   <li>
  <img src="ism/image/slides/flower-729514_1280.jpg">
  <div class="ism-caption ism-caption-0">My slide caption text</div>
  </li>
  <li>
  <img src="ism/image/slides/beautiful-701678_1280.jpg">
  <div class="ism-caption ism-caption-0">My slide caption text</div>
  </li>
  <li>
  <img src="ism/image/slides/summer-192179_1280.jpg">
  <div class="ism-caption ism-caption-0">My slide caption text</div>
  </li>
  </ol>
  </div>
  <p class="ism-badge" id="my-slider-ism-badge"><a class="ism-link"
  href="http://imageslidermaker.com" rel="nofollow">generated with ISM</a></p>

  <section><h1>Your slider in a simple web page</h1>


  <p>This is a working example of your slider.</p>

  <p>To get your slider working in your web page add <em>my-slider.css</em>,    
  <em>ism-2.2.min.js</em> and the slide images to your project directory and paste 
  the markup into your HTML.</p>
  <p>Please see README.txt for more detailed instructions.</p>

  <p>* If your slider is not displayed correctly, please first make sure you have 
  fully extracted the contents of the zip file.</p>

  </section></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

You can download css / images and javascript [from here](https://ufile.io/kv9qpgbo)
note : select slow download when you download the files for free download

Comment: There are much beter modules around if I wanted to use them, example tiny slider, owl carousel etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

here is the working demo but it still needs some update I keep working on code may this help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
body {
  font-family: system-ui;
  background: #f06d06;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.slider-holder {
   width: 50%;
   height: 300px;
   float: left;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background-color: #000;
}

.slider-holder  ul, li {
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   list-style:none;
}

.slider-holder .content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.carousel-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.carousel-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 30px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  cursor: pointer;
}


.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  list-style: none;
}
.carousel-indicators li {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-indent: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(15, 15, 20, 0.7);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
}

.carousel-indicators  li:hover, .carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: red;
}

.carousel-indicators1  {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  list-style: none;
}
.carousel-indicators1  li {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-indent: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgba(15, 15, 20, 0.7);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: opacity 0.6s ease;
}

.carousel-indicators1  li:hover, .carousel-indicators1 li.active {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="slider-holder" id="slider">
         <ul class="image-slide" id="image" >
             <li>
               <div class="img-fluid" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/13/22/53/puzzle-3223941__480.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
                 <div class="content">
                   <h1>Heading</h1>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </li>
             <li>
               <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/07/13/57/puzzle-1721619__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
                 <div class="content">
                   <h1>Heading</h1>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </li>
             <li>
               <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/07/14/13/puzzle-1721635__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
                 <div class="content">
                   <h1>Heading</h1>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </li>
             <li>
               <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/18/20/01/frankfurt-4945405__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
                 <div class="content">
                   <h1>Heading</h1>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </li>
             <li>
               <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/05/11/19/internet-315132__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
                 <div class="content">
                   <h1>Heading</h1>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="carousel-indicators" id="buton">
           <li><span>1</span></li>
           <li><span>2</span></li>
           <li><span>3</span></li>
           <li><span>4</span></li>
           <li><span>5</span></li>
         </ul>
      </div>



<h1> Second slider </h1>
      <div class="slider-holder" id="slider1" style="width: 40%;float:right;">
         <ul class="image-slide" id="image1" >
             <li>
               <div class="img-fluid" style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/03/13/22/53/puzzle-3223941__480.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
                 <div class="content">
                   <h1>Heading</h1>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </li>
             <li>
               <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/07/13/57/puzzle-1721619__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
                 <div class="content">
                   <h1>Heading</h1>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </li>
             <li>
               <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/07/14/13/puzzle-1721635__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
                 <div class="content">
                   <h1>Heading</h1>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </li>
             <li>
               <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/03/18/20/01/frankfurt-4945405__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
                 <div class="content">
                   <h1>Heading</h1>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </li>
             <li>
               <div style="background-image:url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/04/05/11/19/internet-315132__340.jpg); background-position: center; background-size: 100% 100%;height: 300px;">
                 <div class="content">
                   <h1>Heading</h1>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="carousel-indicators1" id="buton">
           <li><span>1</span></li>
           <li><span>2</span></li>
           <li><span>3</span></li>
           <li><span>4</span></li>
           <li><span>5</span></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
<script>
 $(function(){    
var Slider = 0;
$.Slider = function(total){
   $(".carousel-indicators li").removeClass("active");
   $("#image li").hide();
   if (Slider < total -1){
       Slider++;
         $(".carousel-indicators li:eq("+Slider+")").addClass("active");
         $("#image li:eq("+Slider+")").fadeIn("slow");                                    
       }else {
         $(".carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
         $("#image li:first").fadeIn("slow");    
         Slider = 0;    
       }
   }

   var totalLi = $(".carousel-indicators li").length;
   var interval = setInterval('$.Slider('+totalLi+')',5000);
   $("#slider").hover(function(){
      clearInterval(interval);
   },function(){
      interval = setInterval('$.Slider('+totalLi+')',5000);    
   });

   $(".carousel-indicators li:first").addClass("active");
   $("#image li").hide();
   $("#image li:first").show();
   $(".carousel-indicators li").hover(function(){
      var indicators = $(this).index();
      $(".carousel-indicators li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $("#image li").hide();
      $("#image li:eq("+indicators+")").fadeIn("slow");                                   
      Slider = indicators;
      return true;   
   });  
  
  
  var Slider1 = 0;
$.Slider = function(total1){
   $(".carousel-indicators1 li").removeClass("active");
   $("#image1 li").hide();
   if (Slider1 < total1 -1){
       Slider1++;
         $(".carousel-indicators1 li:eq("+Slider1+")").addClass("active");
         $("#image1 li:eq("+Slider1+")").fadeIn("slow");                                    
       }else {
         $(".carousel-indicators1 li:first").addClass("active");
         $("#image1 li:first").fadeIn("slow");    
         Slider1 = 0;    
       }
   }

   var totalLi = $(".carousel-indicators1 li").length;
   var interval = setInterval('$.Slider('+totalLi+')',5000);
   $("#slider1").hover(function(){
      clearInterval(interval);
   },function(){
      interval = setInterval('$.Slider('+totalLi+')',5000);    
   });

   $(".carousel-indicators1 li:first").addClass("active");
   $("#image1 li").hide();
   $("#image1 li:first").show();
   $(".carousel-indicators1 li").hover(function(){
      var indicators1 = $(this).index();
      $(".carousel-indicators1 li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
      $("#image1 li").hide();
      $("#image1 li:eq("+indicators1+")").fadeIn("slow");                                   
      Slider1 = indicators1;
      return true;   
   });  
  
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I dont want to just repeat all codes twice, I could do it if I wanted like that. and both sliders are not working in your demo.

Comment: no problem ,  i am not sure i understood your question properly then , do you want to make the sliders through loops ?

Comment: @Ahmedaminshahin See this example please https://codepen.io/nxworld/pen/kkRpJE it supports multiple sliders, but doesnt have indicators and mouseenter mouseleave functions in it.

Comment: what do you mean by indicators and mouse center ?

Comment: like when you move the mouse on it  , you need the mouse to turn into pointer or indicator ?

Comment: @Ahmedaminshahin (indicators) means controls (dots), simple news ticker is nice, but doesn't have indicators, mouseenter, mouseleave. my slider has all functions except multiple support.